# Positive and Negatives of PVP

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

As the title says, what are the positive and negatives of PVP?

The whole process of breaking the hippie stone and joining the pvp circle makes it appear as a dangerous move to make as a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positives:

1. You gain swagger. Swagger can be used to buy skills, usable items and equipment, and items that give you free food/booze.

Negatives:

1. People can steal your stuff (tradable items, not meat). There are mafia scripts that can closet all your valuables to protect them from attackers.
2. You can lose some substats as well, but I don't remember that loss being anything major.

Since you are new, I doubt you have any extremely expensive items sitting around (unless you got lucky during Crimbo). A number of people also return stolen valuables, though that is not guaranteed.

Comment: yah got lucky with an item from the spookyraven worth 500k meat, but sold it. But people don't just steal stuff just because they can?

Comment: There's a 500k Spookyraven item? Whoa! Anyway, people will steal things occasionally, but I've never had anything big stolen. Also, a meat golem helps: http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Meat_Golem

Comment: Yah at the conservatory. Some weapon that increased familiar weight and familiar XP gain by a lot